# Change LaTeX when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, latex

I am trying to create a program that generates random functions then shows them in LaTeX but I can't figure out how to edit LaTeX when a button is pressed.

This code works:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/latexit.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div lang="latex" id='Latexdiv'></div>

<script>
document.getElementById('Latexdiv').innerHTML = 'sin(x)';
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But this does not:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/latexit.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div lang="latex" id='Latexdiv'></div>
<button onclick="change();">Change the LaTeX</button>

<script>
function change()
{
    document.getElementById('Latexdiv').innerHTML = 'sin(x)';
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use MathJax like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<button onclick='change();'>Change the LaTeX</button>
<div lang='latex' id='Latexdiv'></div>



<script type='text/javascript'>

var latexdiv = document.getElementById('Latexdiv');

function change()
{   
    var latex = document.createElement('script');
    latex.src = 'http://latex.codecogs.com/latexit.js';
    document.head.appendChild(latex);

    var mathjax = document.createElement('script');
    mathjax.src = 'https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML';
    document.head.appendChild(mathjax);

    latexdiv.innerHTML = '\\(sin(x)\\)';
};


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This, unfortunately, only works the first time you press the button. If you press it twice, it just shows 
"\(sin(x)\)" in regular HTML. How would you get it to work twice?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://latex.codecogs.com/latexit.js executes at the end:

```
LatexIT.add('*');
```

That adds and onload listener that executes a render function, that's why works in the first case, the page ends loading after your first script.
You could simply add the render function in your change function.

```
function change()
{
  document.getElementById('Latexdiv').innerHTML = 'sin(x)';
  LatexIT.render('*',false);
}
```